# Basic command line tutorials for Windows and *NIX

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, command-line, shell

I am writing "how-to"s for [Plone CMS](http://plone.org). Often "how-to"s begin with:

> you need to know the basics of command line use..

Are there any really basic tutorials for:

- Windows command line (cd, dir, where is that black prompt box icon)
- Unix, Linux, Ubuntu (cd, ls, cp, etc.)

This would allow us to simply point to these tutorials when we list "basic command line knowledge" as prerequisite for the "how-to"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Linux Command](http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php) has a decent tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this guide](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/) pretty nice, addressing both basic *and* more advanced things.